# Reading CDATA from SimpleXMLElement created with simplexml_import_dom

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument, cdata

I have a portion of an XML file I'm trying to parse. Since it's only a fragment of an XML file its tags aren't closed and is considered invalid markup. Therefore I use a combination of `DOMDocument::loadHTML` and `simplexml_import_dom` to get my XML into a SimpleXMLElement object I can use `xpath` on (important to the project).

All works fine, but I'm unable to get values wrapped in CDATA tags. After hours of debugging it seems to me the CDATA sections are lost upon calling `DOMDocument::loadHTML()`. Here's my method:

```php
$xmlString = "
<items>
    <item>
        <title><![CDATA[Lipsum]]></title>
        <uid><![CDATA[21108541]]></uid>
        <description><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.]]></description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title><![
";
```

..

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($xmlString);

// Traverse into the <body> tag DomDocument has wrapped my XML in
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom->documentElement->childNodes->item(0));

// Traverse further to the item I need (in my project the xpath is variable)
$item = $this->xml->xpath("items/item");

foreach ($item[0] as $child) {
    echo $child->getName(); // This much works, returns "title uid description"
    echo (string) $child; // This doesn't, returns empty string ""
}
```

I've tried using `dom_import_xml($child)` to try and find a CDATA Section within the node, but without success. At any point after `loadHTML()` the CDATA bit and everything in it seems nowhere to be found.

Other solutions on stackoverflow include passing the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` constant when creating the `SimpleXMLElement` instance, but `simplexml_import_dom` doesn't accept such a parameter. `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` does, but it then returns empty DOMText nodes instead

Comment: It might be news to you, but there is no CDATA in HTML (check HTML specs, it's not in here), so it's not supported via [`loadHTML`](http://php.net/domdocument.loadHTML): https://eval.in/59110 - I hope that doesn't destroy any dreams, you probably want to load it as XML?

Comment: Thanks for this insight. `loadXML` couldn't be of service to me either as my XMLstring is incomplete. All in all I've given up on the DOMDocument parser family for this particular case. My solution is to parse the fragment with good old [XML Parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php) and its `xml_parse_into_struc` function. It doesn't require valid XML, reads CDATA and somebody posted a handy xml2array function on php.net which is as good as using xpath. Thanks!

Comment: Well, if that's the issue, you're probably looking for `->recover = TRUE` - https://eval.in/59174 (combine that with internal errors then you don't get the errors to display, I just left that in to show you that actual recovering is done) - more drastic here: https://eval.in/59176

Comment: Another caveat I ran into is that `loadHTML()` puts all nodenames in lowercase. `loadXML()` is my way to go and `->recover = TRUE` did the trick! You're a lifesaver

Comment: For future reference, note that this is an example of [the X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): your actual problem was "How do I parse an invalid XML file using DOM/SimpleXML?" but instead you asked a detailed question about an attempted solution which wasn't going to work for you.